# Optional methods without cluttering extending types

Tags: java, oop, interface

This is a Best Practices kind of question.

Let's say I have an abstract class `Screen` that implements some interfaces.

Now the thing is, the interfaces add a ton of methods and I'm sure not all screen implementations will make use of them.

I'm wondering what's the most-common and cleaner way to do this.

1. **Just leave them abstract**

   Adds clutter in extending classes

   ```
   protected abstract void onFocus();
   ```
2. **Add empty body**

   Not good for someone not familiar with the extended class, they perhaps may worry if it's okay to override them.

   ```
   protected void onFocus() {
       // no impl
   }
   ```
3. **Make some description annotation?**

   I'm not sure this is a good use for them tho.

   ```
   @NotImplemented
   protected void onFocus() {
       // no impl
   }
   ```

What'd you consider best?

Comment: I like first option if each Screen has different implementation for this method or optionally they can choose not to implement by just throwing `NotSupportedOperationException` or something similar

Comment: In Java 8 you could also implement `default` methods in the interfaces themselves.

Comment: I know that, unfortunately I think it'll take at least two years until Java 8 can be used in production.

Comment: In that case, the usual practice is to implement them and make them throw some sort of `NotImplementedException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only option two (Add empty body) keep requirement of 'optional' method. I would prefer to not force all extenders to implement all optional methods, this will make them not optional, right?. Probably you could write base abstract class/classes to provide some default behavior which will make using you API simpler. SpirngMVC is using this pattern to allow you executing some logic during different life cycles of controllers.